# MassTransit transactional publishing

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, rabbitmq, masstransit

I can't figure out how I can publish a message transactional using MassTransit 3.1.2 and RabbitMQ 3.6.0. I have a basic scenario where I save something to the database and then I want to publish an event. Wrapping a System.Transactions.TransactionScope around it does not work, before I complete the scope the message is already sent:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
     // Save to database here.

     bus.Publish(new EntityCreatedEvent());

     // Event is already published at this point.

     scope.Complete();
}
```

The bus is created as follows:

```
var rabbitMqHostAddress = new Uri($"rabbitmq://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMqHost"]}/");

var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(r =>
{
    r.Host(rabbitMqHostAddress, h =>
    {
        h.Username(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMqUsername"]);
        h.Password(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMqPassword"]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you solve this in any way?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ does not enroll in transactions. This is not possible.

Comment: If I check https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html it says it has transactional publish and ack, so it shoud be possible right?

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while for this, and I might not have understood the question correctly but if you want to raise the event after the database transaction is done you can probably do something like this

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
 // Save to database here.

scope.TransactionCompleted += (sender, args) => { bus.Publish(new EntityCreatedEvent()); };

 // Event is already published at this point.

 scope.Complete();
}
```